# Syntax: Using case or if-then-else for t-SQL alias setting?

Tags: sql-server, list, if-statement, case, alias

I'm using t-SQL for reporting and had a question regarding syntax. I just started learning some of the more intermediate SQL stuff, like joins, aliases, case statements, order by, etc.

I have a table that I need to pull person data from. When pulling data I need to pull every person associated and sort through the list of people based on attributes. Then I want to store the person data in two variables (aliases). One person has attribute 'Applicant' and their information should be aliased and stored separately from everyone else's. Everyone else should be stored in a single list. Is there a good way to do this in SQL? Here's what I was thinking in pseudocode

```
select * from persontable
if persontable.TYPE = 'Applicant' then persontable.name as applName, persontable.otherAtt as applOtherAtt --etc
else persontable.name --add to a list and alias as otherNames
```

or something like this

```
case when persontable.TYPE = 'Applicant'then persontable.name as applName, persontable.otherAtt as applOtherAtt --etc
else persontable.name --add to a list and alias as otherNames
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand the question (for me, at least). Could you please share your table(s) structures, some sample data, and the result you'd like to get for that sample?

Comment: @Mureinik Sorry, I'm not allowed to share the table structure. I thought I did a pretty good job with the mockups above, what's confusing you?

Pull person from database then if person = Applicant, store applicant's info in several aliases

Else if person is not an applicant, add their name to the list of not applicants.

Comment: Your question is confusing because you talk about storing data in two variables.  Your pseudo-code doesn't have any variables.   Variables hold scalar data, so you can't do a multi-row SELECT that populates them.   It's really unclear what you're trying to do.   Maybe this will help you:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669192/t-sql-select-case-vs-if-else-and-explaination-about-begin

Comment: @TabAlleman It's alright, I figured out how to get it to work.

I guess I was referring to aliases as variables and the filtered data that you get from using a case statement or if-then-else as the value of said "variables".

Comment: @TabAlleman That link had exactly what I needed. The if begin end structure is perfect for what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Marking as answered, looked up the difference between variables and aliases and was provided with a link to some easily followable if-then-else logic.